# insert dtype in std::map

Tags: c++, numpy, stdmap, pybind11

I want to do a map that takes a pair of `pybind11::dtype` and `int` and maps it into an OpenCV format:

```
static std::map<std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int>, int> ocv_types;
```

So I  `insert`ed all combinations but there seems to be a problem when adding `int32_t` and `float_t`:

```
    ocv_types.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(pybind11::dtype::of<std::int32_t>() , 3), CV_32SC3));

    ocv_types.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(pybind11::dtype::of<std::float_t>() , 3), CV_32FC3));
```

When I do this, **only** the `CV_32SC3` is really `insert`ed , **my guess** that somewhere the program "thinks" that both elements are equal and therefore is not going to insert the second one.

How can I actually add these 2?

**P.S.** I did this check just to "prove" that the types are not equal:

```
    if(pybind11::dtype::of<std::int32_t>() == pybind11::dtype::of<std::float_t>())
    {
        std::cout << "std::int32_t == std::float_t" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "std::int32_t != std::float_t" << std::endl;
    }
```

... And of course they are not.

**EDIT**

I added the `<` function for `dtype` and used it in the compare function for the map, but not all elements are present in the map:

```
int getVal(pybind11::dtype type)
{
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::uint8_t>()))
        return 1;
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::uint16_t>()))
        return 2;
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::int16_t>()))
        return 3;
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::int32_t>()))
        return 4;
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::float_t>()))
        return 5;
    if(type.is(pybind11::dtype::of<std::double_t>()))
        return 6;
}

inline bool operator <(const pybind11::dtype a, const pybind11::dtype b) //friend claim has to be here
{
    return getVal(a) < getVal(b);
}

auto comp = [](const std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int> a, const std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int> b)
{
    return a < b;
};
static std::map<std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int>, int, decltype(comp)> ocv_types(comp);
```

Comment: You need to write your own comparator and differentiate the keys as needed. `std::map` takes this as the third argument of the template specialization. **Be advised that the map deduces equal elements by switching their position in the comparator predicate. If both times it gets `false`, then the elements are considered equal**

Comment: @TheDreamsWind  I tested comapring the pairs using `==` and the result was that the pairs are not equal... you mean that `std::map` won't use `==` ?

Comment: it doesn't, the predicate uses the `less` idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted `pybind11::dtype` do not have any particular order.
So IMO best approach is to use `std::unordered_map` and provide respective hashes. `pybind11` already has some [hash function](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv44hash6handle), so it is needed to adopt it for `std::hash`.

Here is test I've wrote (using Catch2) and it passes on my machine:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "catch2/catch_all.hpp"
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <unordered_map>

template<>
struct std::hash<pybind11::dtype>
{
    size_t operator()(const pybind11::dtype &t) const
    {
        return pybind11::hash(t);
    }
};

template<>
struct std::hash<std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int>>
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int> &t) const
    {
        return std::hash<pybind11::dtype>{}(t.first) ^ static_cast<size_t>(t.second);
    }
};


TEST_CASE("map_with_dtype") {
    constexpr auto CV_32SC3 = 1;
    constexpr auto CV_32FC3 = 2;

    pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    std::unordered_map<std::pair<pybind11::dtype, int>, int> ocv_types;
    REQUIRE(ocv_types.empty());

    auto a = ocv_types.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(pybind11::dtype::of<std::int32_t>() , 3), CV_32SC3));
    REQUIRE(a.second);

    auto b = ocv_types.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(pybind11::dtype::of<std::float_t>() , 3), CV_32FC3));
    REQUIRE(b.second);
    CHECK(b.first->second == CV_32FC3);

    CHECK(ocv_types.size() == 2);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# set the project name
project(MapOfPyBind11)

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

# add the executable
add_executable(MapOfPyBind11Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MapOfPyBind11Test PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2 pybind11::module pybind11::embed)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(MapOfPyBind11Test)
```